# Executable files on my computer cannot be executed and cannot be run by terminal

Tags: permissions, executable

I'm really new to ubuntu and linux, so everything has flown straight over my head, but this problem is obviously not normal. I've looked all over the place for a solution to this problem, but all the answers to related issues have not helped.

This is just the most recent example, but it applies to all executable programs. Programs do not run, and I receive this message when I do not allow to execute file as program:

> **Could not display “starbound”.**
>
> **There is no application installed for “executable” files.
>   Do you want to search for an application to open this file?**

When I go to the program's properties and check the box allowing it to run as a program, it simply does nothing.

When I try to run the program through the terminal, it will not allow me. It even shows "starbound" in the ls display. This is the full terminal entry:

```
root@john-System-Product-Name:/home/john/Extracted_Games/Starbound/linux64# ls
asset_packer      launch_starbound_server.sh  libGLEW.so.1.7  starbound.ico
bootstrap.config  launch_starbound.sh         starbound       starbound_server
root@john-System-Product-Name:/home/john/Extracted_Games/Starbound/linux64# ./starbound
bash: ./starbound: Permission denied
```

If anyone has a fix or possible explanation for this please respond.

Comment: what kind of file you are trying to execute??

Comment: If @falconer 's answer does not work, please add the output of `ls -l` from the directory -  `cd /home/john/Extracted_Games/Starbound/linux64`

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the file executable: Just right click on the file -> **Properties** -> **Permissions** -> check **Allow executing file as program**.

Or from terminal:

```
chmod u+x starbound
```

**Update:** I missed that you wrote that even if you tried checking the box to allow the program to execute it did nothing. That is another problem that the program is not showing up. It can be a program error, error with your setup, or if it is a terminal app then it won't show up if you start it by double clicking it. I don't know what kind of program is this so I can't help until you give us some directions. But what you should try:

```
chmod u+x starbound launch_starbound.sh launch_starbound_server.sh starbound_server
```

So we made all those files executable which based on their names should be executable. After this please try running launch_starbound.sh from terminal:

```
./launch_starbound.sh
```

Does it report errors? Maybe the server thing should be started first? Try running launch_starbound_server.sh first from terminal. Does it report errors?

Comment: The original poster stated, "When I go to the program's properties and check the box allowing it to run as a program, it simply does nothing."

Comment: Ohh. I missed that. Thank you for pointing that out. I updated my answer.

Comment: Running `chmod` as root can sometimes help, also the OP needs to run `cd /home/john/Extracted_Games/Starbound/linux64` before doing everything else.

Comment: @wilf feel free to edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm right in believing you have right clicked on the executable itself, went to properties, went to permissions, and checked "Allow executing file as program" and that didn't succeed

Seems to me (upon looking at starbound and my best guess being it is a game) I feel you are trying to run a Microsoft Windows application under linux, which just isn't going to work.

You need to either use `WINE` to run windows executables ***or*** (I believe this game is available through steam) download **steam for ubuntu**, which I believe is even available through the ubuntu software center, and run the game from the steam client itself.